# How to Register a new user on Firebase in Clojurescript using Matchbox

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to register a new user to my firebase using the Matchbox Library (https://github.com/crisptrutski/matchbox/blob/master/src/matchbox/core.cljc). My current code looks like this

`(defn makeUser [email password]
  (m/create-user r email password))`

where I pass in the email and password from an form. When I run this, however, nothing happens. No errors and no new users appear in the database.